Pass a variable to remote session without leaving the session
I have a code that I use to pass a profile to a remote machine. But I also need to pass a variable without leaving the session. Is there such a possibility? For example, I need to pass the value of a variable $var1
$var1 = 'some text'

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName <Server> 
Invoke-Command -FilePath $profile -Session $session
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
$var1 ?


You can use Invoke-Command as many times as you want:
$var1 = 'some text'

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName <Server> 
Invoke-Command -FilePath $profile -Session $session
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $var1 = $using:var1 } -Session $session
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
$var1 ?

